# SSL for domain without hosting

Tags: redirects, https, security-certificate, 302-redirect

I purchased a domain that we'll call example.sh that has no hosting and simply redirects to my profile page on another site. When a user visits `http://example.sh/` they are taken to `https://othersite.com/profile` with the browser indicating a 302 response.

However, a query for `https://example.sh/` fails to resolve because there is no SSL certificate associated with the domain. My domain registrar offers SSL in their admin panel, but when I activated this feature and asked for assistance in installing it, they said it couldn't be done because I have no hosting.

Is there any way to make https://example.sh/ a working URL without purchasing hosting? I have an account with DreamHost, but I wasn't able to use them for this domain because I need the unusual .sh TLD.

Answer (score 1):

Many domain name providers provide URL redirection or forwarding.

For example, in GoDaddy, you can click on your Domain >>> DNS >>> forwarding and configure your domain.sh to forward everything to othersite.com/profile

However, for **https redirections**, it requires a few extra steps (like emitting a valid certificate). Unfortunately at the moment, GoDaddy doesn't provide SSL Domain Redirections in their redirection service.

Comment: If I purchase a domain from GoDaddy, will I be able to use the https schema without buying hosting?

Comment: It will redirect any request (http or https) to your other domain. Mind you that GoDaddy doesn't have custom redirects or paths, it's all or nothing to a single destination. Other registrars might offer you more control over the redirections, but for a simple site, it should be more than enough (without buying hosting).

Comment: I'm sorry, please scratch my previous answer. I just tested it on a domain I own, and GoDaddy doesn't redirect https natively... I'm going to edit the answer accordingly.